Any Difference between "torch.distributions.normal.Normal" v.s. "torch.distributions.Normal"
I only see "torch.distributions.normal.Normal" in the official documents but never see "torch.distributions.Normal". However, I sometimes see people use "torch.distributions.Normal" in their codes in Github. Could anyone explain if there is any difference between these two usages? Thanks a lot!

Programming questions or questions about specific software are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

This is a common Python pattern where packages expose their important classes at a higher level for convenience while maintaining organized internal structure. The actual implementation is in torch.distributions.normal.Normal, but it's registered in torch.distributions.__init__.py to be directly accessible as shown below.
from .normal import Normal

__all__ = [... "Normal",...]


Thanks! But why use from .normal import Normal instead of from normal import Normal, since init.py and normal.py are in the same directory?

That is the correct relative import to ensure that Python will look for the normal.py module relative to the current package. Yours is absolute import from the global Python module namespace which assumes that the normal.py module has been already installed as part of the Python venv or is accessible as a top-level module. Of course the relative one is safer and better as public API. Hope this clarifies which is not AI theory but Python module import programming question.

In addition, since from .normal import Normal already gets Normal, why do we still need __all__ = [... "Normal",...]?

The __all__ attribute controls what is publicly accessible when someone imports the module or package using import *. This gives you the ability to hide internal implementation details and only expose the necessary classes, functions, or variables that make up the module's "public API". Some programmers might be lazy and just import *, where they can still invoke Normal module.

If you consider my answer is helpful or resolved your lingering confusion, please upvote or accept it. Thank you.

Your answer is really helpful! But I'm a new asker, so I cannot upvote until I have 15 reputations... I don't know why the platform designed this rule.

Yes I know, but I'm sure you can accept answer by clicking near the answer icon.

Ok! I guess I have done that. Please let me know if I have not successfully done so.

Programming questions are off-topic here. Please, vote to close them instead of answering them. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
